# Correlation heat map for windows presentation foundation

Tags: wpf, visualization, data-visualization, heatmap

Does anyone knows any good tool for drawing correlation heat maps for WPF?

Example based on comments:

[image]

Original image [source](http://lcchong.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/image_thumb.png?w=644&h=206)

Comment: Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map for the definition of a heat map..  What you're asking for isn't one, sorry.  At best I'd say you're asking for how to change the background of a cell in a table...

Answer (score 8):

The free WPF Toolkit has a TreeMap. You can define it in XAML as follows:

```
<vis:TreeMap ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HeatMap.Sectors}"
              Interpolators="{StaticResource colourInterpolator}">
  <vis:TreeMap.ItemDefinition>
    <vis:TreeMapItemDefinition ValueBinding="{Binding MarketCap}">
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Border x:Name="Border"
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  BorderThickness="1"
                  Margin="1"
                  Opacity="0.5">                      
          </Border>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     FontSize="20"
                     Margin="5"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </vis:TreeMapItemDefinition>
  </vis:TreeMap.ItemDefinition>
</vis:TreeMap>
```

The above XAML is a snippet from an application I have written that shows financial HeatMaps. You can see a Silverlight version running here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/xaml-finance/

(Just hit the 'heatmap' button)

Comment: It seems a bit different from what I want. 
I'm looking for a correlation heatmap like this - http://lcchong.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/image_thumb.png?w=644&h=206
Thanks anyway

Comment: OK - you need a DataGrid! There is a perfectly good DataGrid that is part of the WPF framework.

Comment: I think I'll go down that route :)

Comment: Datagrid on its own provides no simple method to do a heatmap

Comment: @rolls, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a commercial product, I would suggest you look at the Telerik controls.  Telerik has excellent controls for WPF.  Included in the long list is a Heat Map control.  Here is a link to the site where they list the heat map feature:

http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/map.aspx

If you are looking to build something, here are a couple blog articles that lay out how to do it (with source provided):

http://www.garrettgirod.com/?p=111

http://www.nickdarnell.com/?p=833

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm looking for a correlation heatmap like this - http://lcchong.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/image_thumb.png?w=644&h=206

Answer (score 2):

The Syncfusion [charting component](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/wpf/chart/overview#heatmaps) appears to provide heatmaps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm looking for a correlation heatmap like this - http://lcchong.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/image_thumb.png?w=644&h=206

Comment: @Xenofonte: I've edited your question to include this. As other have stated this is similar to a datagrid, but there is probably some code to write and maintain for the visualization you want. It is worth checking if the syncfusion or telerik controls require less customization.

Answer (score 1):

Not a free component, but if you can get your hands on the Telerik library you could use the following:

http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/heatmap.aspx

I have had to use it in the past for a few projects and it worked pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I used DevExpress with a custom ColorFormatter behaviour. I couldn't find anything on the market that did this out of the box. This took me a few days to develop. My code attaached below, hopefully this helps someone out there.

Edit: I used POCO view models and MVVM however you could change this to not use POCO if you desire.

[image: Example]

Table2DViewModel.cs

```
namespace ViewModel
{
    [POCOViewModel]
    public class Table2DViewModel
    {
        public ITable2DView Table2DView { get; set; }

        public DataTable ItemsTable { get; set; }


        public Table2DViewModel()
        {
        }

        public Table2DViewModel(MainViewModel mainViewModel, ITable2DView table2DView) : base(mainViewModel)
        {
            Table2DView = table2DView;   
            CreateTable();
        }

        private void CreateTable()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            var xAxisStrings = new string[]{"X1","X2","X3"};
            var yAxisStrings = new string[]{"Y1","Y2","Y3"};

            //TODO determine your min, max number for your colours
            var minValue = 0;
            var maxValue = 100;
            Table2DView.SetColorFormatter(minValue,maxValue, null);

            //Add the columns
            dt.Columns.Add(" ", typeof(string));
            foreach (var x in xAxisStrings) dt.Columns.Add(x, typeof(double));

            //Add all the values
            double z = 0;
            for (var y = 0; y < yAxisStrings.Length; y++)
            {
                var dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[" "] = yAxisStrings[y];
                for (var x = 0; x < xAxisStrings.Length; x++)
                {
                    //TODO put your actual values here!
                    dr[xAxisStrings[x]] = z++; //Add a random values
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            ItemsTable = dt;
        }


        public static Table2DViewModel Create(MainViewModel mainViewModel, ITable2DView table2DView)
        {
            var factory = ViewModelSource.Factory((MainViewModel mainVm, ITable2DView view) => new Table2DViewModel(mainVm, view));
            return factory(mainViewModel, table2DView);
        }
    }

}
```

ITable2DView.cs

```
namespace Interfaces
    {
        public interface ITable2DView
        {
            void SetColorFormatter(float minValue, float maxValue, ColorScaleFormat colorScaleFormat);
        }
    }
```

Table2DView.xaml.cs

```
namespace View
{
    public partial class Table2DView : ITable2DView
    {
        public Table2DView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static ColorScaleFormat defaultColorScaleFormat = new ColorScaleFormat
        {
            ColorMin = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFF8696B"),
            ColorMiddle = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFFEB84"),
            ColorMax = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF63BE7B")
        };

        public void SetColorFormatter(float minValue, float maxValue, ColorScaleFormat colorScaleFormat = null)
        {
            if (colorScaleFormat == null) colorScaleFormat = defaultColorScaleFormat;
            ConditionBehavior.MinValue = minValue;
            ConditionBehavior.MaxValue = maxValue;
            ConditionBehavior.ColorScaleFormat = colorScaleFormat;
        }
    }
}
```

DynamicConditionBehavior.cs

```
namespace Behaviors
{
    public class DynamicConditionBehavior : Behavior<GridControl>
    {
        GridControl Grid => AssociatedObject;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            Grid.ItemsSourceChanged += OnItemsSourceChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            Grid.ItemsSourceChanged -= OnItemsSourceChanged;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        public ColorScaleFormat ColorScaleFormat { get; set;}
        public float MinValue { get; set; }
        public float MaxValue { get; set; }

        private void OnItemsSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var view = Grid.View as TableView;

            if (view == null) return;

            view.FormatConditions.Clear();

            foreach (var col in Grid.Columns)
            {
                view.FormatConditions.Add(new ColorScaleFormatCondition
                {
                    MinValue = MinValue,
                    MaxValue = MaxValue,
                    FieldName = col.FieldName,
                    Format = ColorScaleFormat,
                });
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Table2DView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm" 
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:ViewModel"
             xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
             xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Behaviors"
             xmlns:dxdo="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking"
             DataContext="{dxmvvm:ViewModelSource Type={x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel}}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxg:GridColumn}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxg:HeaderItemsControl}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

        <!--<dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="" Command="{Binding OnLoadedCommand}"/>
        </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>-->
        <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsTable}"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew"
                     EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True">

        <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors >
            <behaviors:DynamicConditionBehavior x:Name="ConditionBehavior" />
            </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView ShowGroupPanel="False"
                           AllowPerPixelScrolling="True"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
        </dxg:GridControl>
  </UserControl>
```