# How to change single cell color of datagrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

[image: stage chart]
I want to change background color of a particular cell of this grid at runtime(show booked seats).i am binding this grid from datatable on window loaded event.i have a record of seats like 'A33'.my code for binding is like this.

```
MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(str);
mycon.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from Stage", mycon);
da.Fill(dt);
MyGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 5):

change background of specific cell by code :

```
   DataGridRow firstRow = dataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataGrid1.Items[0]) as DataGridRow;
   DataGridCell firstColumnInFirstRow = dataGrid1.Columns[0].GetCellContent(firstRow).Parent as DataGridCell;
   //set background
   firstColumnInFirstRow.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: Using the `ItemContainerGenerator` should be avoided in general, it's ugly and fails on virtualized controls.

Answer (score 5):

Your cell-data should have a property `IsBooked`, then in the `DataGrid.CellStyle` you can use a data-trigger on `IsBooked` to change its backgroud. (There are [some other alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5551986/546730) besides `DataTriggers`, but if you just have one boolean conditional i find them to be quite convenient.)

Comment: Can you please help me  how to do this? i am new in wpf.

Comment: You should acquaint yourself with WPF then, read the [articles on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms754130.aspx) and questions here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @H.B. I see u are good with WPF so I would be happy if u could help me with my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645688/how-to-set-background-of-a-datagrid-cell-during-autogeneratingcolumn-event-depen, please.