# Programmatically Change Cell Colour

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two lists of `Ints` which I need to place into two vertical columns side by side. Where the numbers do not match I need to hightlight this (one or both cells, doesn't matter which. Changing background or font colour, doesn't matter which).

I initially was displaying these in side by side `ListBoxes` but when I found it hard to change the colour of a specific cell programmatically I started looking at `DataGrid`, but this too proved difficult + many of the guides I found online appear to be Windows Forms focused, not WPF.

For what I thought would be a simple task what would be the recommended control and please guide me as to how to identify these differing cells/indexes and also update their appearance.

Extra info: Both lists will not be terribly long (<15 each).

I have tried this when I was using the datagrid;

```
dgdResults.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGrid/ListBox are ItemsControls and work well with a single collection. I suggest to create additional list of objects with a pair of items from list1 and list2 *and* attribute which indicates different items, and then display that list in UI.

```
var L1 = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var L2 = new List<int> {1, 2, 0, 4, 5};
var results = L1.Zip(L2, (i, j) => new {Previous = i, Current = j, IsDifferent = i != j});
ListResults.ItemsSource = results;
```

```
<ItemsControl Name="ListResults">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1">
                <UniformGrid.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="UniformGrid">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDifferent}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Crimson"/>
                          </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </UniformGrid.Style>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Previous}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Current}"/>
            </UniformGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

[image: diff]

---

Alternative with DataTable/DataGrid

```
var L1 = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var L2 = new List<int> {1, 2, 0, 4, 5};

var dt = new DataTable
            {
                Columns =
                {
                    {"Previous", typeof (int)},
                    {"Current", typeof (int)},
                    {"IsDifferent", typeof (bool)},
                }
            };
for (int x = 0; x < L1.Count; x++)
    dt.Rows.Add(L1[x], L2[x], L1[x] != L2[x]);

DgResults.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

```
<DataGrid Name="DgResults" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDifferent}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Crimson"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Previous}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Current}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Attribute `IsDifferent` is used in a DataTrigger to change background

Comment: Awesome and straightforward! Is there a way to modify the `ItemSource` line to use a DataTable with the columns Previous,Current,IsDifferent instead?

Comment: @windowskm, yes: `ListResults.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;`

Answer (score 1):

From here [How to change single cell color of datagrid in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189717/how-to-change-single-cell-color-of-datagrid-in-wpf) and the answer by user1064519 I get that

```
DataGridRow firstRow = dataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataGrid1.Items[0]) as DataGridRow;
DataGridCell firstColumnInFirstRow = dataGrid1.Columns[0].GetCellContent(firstRow).Parent as DataGridCell;
firstColumnInFirstRow.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

That workds for me! Obviously change the index for other rows/columns

Answer (score 0):

In your app.xaml create a style that you want to use for the row thats not matching.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

If you then enumerate the rows and find one that does not match you can set the style like this

```
Style style = Application.Current.FindResource("DataGridRow") as Style;
row.Style = style;
```