# WPF - Change DataGridTemplateColumn cell background based on CheckBox value

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I need to change the background color of a DataGridTemplateColumn cell based on whether or not the CheckBox within the DataGridTemplateColumn is checked. Seems that this should be possible within xaml, how can I go about this?

Column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FSC-P" Width="SizeToHeader">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding FSCP}" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values) however, this is not working for a TemplateColumn. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please consider using `DataTrigger`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `Style` will change the `Background` color of the `Cell` if the `CheckBox` is checked:

```
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cb"
                              IsChecked="{Binding FSCP, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FSCP, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="FSC-P" Width="SizeToHeader" CellStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxCellStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Richard E, this worked. In the meantime, I found this: http://asimsajjad.blogspot.com/2010/09/changing-background-color-of-datagrid.html, which is essentially the same thing minus the UpdateSourceTrigger. Thanks again