# WPF:Using checkbox IsChecked property in DataTrigger

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to use WPF checkbox's IsChecked property in a DataTrigger.Based on the value i am setting particular DataGridRow's background.

My NOT WORKING code

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chkbox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="40" Width="Auto" Header="Select">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox  x:Name="chkbox" IsChecked="{Binding Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

Then I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618077/wpf-change-datagridtemplatecolumn-cell-background-based-on-checkbox-value) and changed the code as below and it is working fine.Here **Selected** is my public property.

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan" />
                      </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Please help me to understand why my original code is not working? am i missing anything.
google did not help.surprisingly there is no thread for this on SO also! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code is not working because you're trying to locate an object via `ElementName` which exists as a templated object, and thus isn't created until *after* the binding tries to resolve. Generally, you should only use `ElementName` when referring to ancestor objects in the visual tree, and not to children, particularly templated children.

As mentioned in comments, it would also not be possible to use a `{RelativeSource FindAncestor...` binding here because the `CheckBox` is a child, not an ancestor, of the `DataGridRow`

Comment: Can we use FindAncestor and AncestorLevel in this binding ?

Comment: @NirajDoshi I don't think so, because the CheckBox is a Child of DataGridRow, not an Ancestor. I'd recommend just using the bound value in your DataTrigger, like you have in your second code block.

Comment: @Rachel: Makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Indeed - I'll integrate this into my answer

Comment: @Aravol ,you mean there is no way to bind to a child element.but by the time trigger fires control would have been created right?

Comment: There are ways to bind to child elements, but not using `ElementName`. Basically this is a case where you should be using bound data