# WPF: Set a cell color based on other multiple values in other columns?

Tags: wpf

I want to change the Abs(Diff) column. This has to be in Abs(Diff) because the viewer wants to see it this way.

```
 ID  | TYPE| CURRENT VALUE | TARGET       | ABS(Diff)
  1  | Sell| 10            |  11          | 1        --> Color Red
  2  | Sell| 11            |  10          | 1        --> Color Green
  3  | BUY | 10            |  9           | 1        --> Color Green
  4  | BUY | 10            |  11          | 1        --> Color Red
```

The meaning:
Row 1: I have an item to sell. Current Market value is 10, I am looking to sell when it is at least(Target) 11. This does not meet my requirement. The color should be red in the cell for Abs(Diff)

I have looked at this. [Change DataGrid cell colour based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values)
 But this seems to be one value only. How do I look at multiple columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a `bool` property named `IsPositive` that signifies whether the `ABS(Diff)` value is positive or negative. Maybe something like this:

```
public bool IsPositive
{
    get { return Diff >= 0; }
}
```

Then you'd need to do this to make sure that it updates in the UI when the `Diff` value changes:

```
public double Diff 
{
    get { return diff; }
    set
    {
        diff = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Diff");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsPositive");
    }
}
```

Then you *should* be able to do something like this (adapted from the example in your linked question):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Abs}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPositive}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPositive}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Abs}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: The second DataTrigger is when Value="False". Thanks I didn't know how to set up the xaml.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for pointing that out, I'll update the code example.

Answer (score 2):

> But this seems to be one value only. How do I look at multiple
>   columns?

If that's the 'only' problem, you should be creating another property in your ViewModel `public bool ShouldColor`, and have the desired logic there.

Or, you can achieve that by using [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If I set the ShouldColor column. How would Abs(Diff) color change color based the ShouldColor column? What is that in xaml?

Comment: Multibinding in that example sets the value of the text. I still need to have the value to be 1. Is there a hidden value or something else I'm missing?