# WPF DataGrid: setting style for an individual cell

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to change the foreground color of a `DataGrid` cell.

I am trying to use a class extending `IMultiValueConverter` and I'd like to bind it the item used to generate a row and to the name of the column.

I read other Q&A and I saw they suggest to use a `MultiBinding` but I am not sure about how I could add the bindings

Comment: I think that you might have some trouble doing that. To access the cell, you'd generally use the `DataGrid.CellStyle` Property and to access the row, you'd usually use the `DataGrid.RowStyle` Property, so combining them might be tricky. What *exactly* are you trying to do... there might be a better (or easier) way to accomplish it.

Comment: Are you trying to change foreground in a random cell or in some specific column only?

Comment: My high level goal is to change the foreground color of the cells that have a different value than the cell in the same column in the previous (according to the original sorting) row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue.

I needed to change the properties I wanted to highlight with a different color decorating them so that they now contain the information about whether their value needed special formatting.

Then I created a binding for each `DataGrid` column as it is described in [this other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values). I bound the decorated property and I used an `IValueConverter` to obtain the `Brush` color I wanted to use.