# Color DataGridCell by Cellvalue

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, datagridcell

i've a WPF DataGrid with different count of columns. I want to color the single cells dependent by the value.
For example: If the cell-value is 0, then red.

These are my experiments:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="DataGrid"  SelectionUnit="Cell">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                  <!--experiment 1 -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                   <!--experiment 2 -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: show us your DataGrid Xaml !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values  Ans already here

Comment: I already tried this before.
   <Trigger Property="Content"  Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                            </Trigger>
 But it seems that the content is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a value converter (with the cell value as a parameter), that returns the color you want.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGridCell Background="{Binding CellValueField, Converter={StaticResource YourDefinedValueToColorConverter}}" />
</DataGrid>
```

---

EDIT: Finally got it to work.

Converter and style definitions:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <c:ValueToColorConverter x:Key="ValueToColorConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource ValueToColorConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="10,10,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ValueToColorConverter}}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

And the converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var cell = value as Order;
        if (cell != null && cell.Size > 80)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        else return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    }
```

I used the `DataGrid_Loaded` method to fill the DataGrid with some random data encapsulated in a sample class:

```
class Order
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: I have a various count of columns

Comment: Ok then, that was just a crude example. You can use converters in a cell style definition.
`<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding CellValueField, Converter={StaticResource YourDefinedValueToColorConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>`

Comment: This I've already tried. If I debug, I don't see the contents of the cell.

Comment: Try adding a Foreground setter to the style - maybe it's defaulting to the background color.

Comment: Thanks for the complete example. I tried to build the same, but it unfortunately doesn't work. Cell is null.

Comment: Does `value` have any... value, or is it null as well? If it does, then the value is probably being lost during casting.

Comment: Make sure you're populating the datagrid's ItemsSource correctly, because maybe there is just no data to show.

Comment: datagrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();

Comment: I solved the problem by using the OnAutoGeneratingColum-EventHandler in combination with your answer. Thanks alot!
Now, I have to include the value of the first column in the IValue-Converter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a value converter, like this:

```
<DataGridCell Background="{Binding CellValueField, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToColorValueConverter}}" />
```

And:

```
public class IntegerToColorValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch ((int)value)
        {
            case 1: return Color.Red; break;
            case 2: return Color.Yellow; break;
            Default: return Color.White; break;
        }
    }

}
```