# datagridcell custom template for null value?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

I'm attempting to populate a datagrid and I would like null cells to have a specific template.

On searching, I have come across a few different similar examples such as [Color DataGridCell by Cellvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010317/color-datagridcell-by-cellvalue). This example sets the background color to the cell using a converter, but from what I have been reading, I do not believe that a converter would work for stetting a template.

Any suggsetions on how I could properly go about doing so? To be specific, I am looking to display the text NULL whenever the cell content is null (but not for an empty string). As far as I can tell a template would be the proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a simple workaround: use `Binding.TargetNullValue` property

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=StringValue, TargetNullValue='NULL'}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

if `StringValue` is null, it will be displayed as `NULL`