# WPF: passing datagridrow object to converter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, ivalueconverter

I've got a problem with passing object to converter in WPF.

My DataGrid looks like:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="customTasksDataGrid" Margin="10,10,10,38" Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource converter}, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Klient" Binding="{Binding Client.Names}"/>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Converter:

```
public class DateToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CustomTask t = (CustomTask)value;
        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString()); // HERE
        ...
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When running my prog marked line throws error, that my CustomTask t object is null. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

As **Vadim Martynov** suggested I change my converter to:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
        return null;
    CustomTask t = (CustomTask)value;
    ...
}
```

And it works perfectly now! Thanks

Comment: What happens if you take out the call to the converter, ie replace with:      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Client.Names}"/> does the client name show in the tooltip?

Comment: @Stew52 no in this case converter never calls

Comment: it won't do because you have removed it.  but does it show what you would expect? ie is the data context for the tooltip what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next code works fine for me:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Also I noticed that there is only one call with null value in your code. Next calls (if your binding does not fail) will have not null CustomTask value (when you actually call Tooltip) and will fork fine. Then just add if(t == null) return null; to your converter and everything will work fine.

```
public class DateToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    CustomTask t = (CustomTask)value;
    if(t == null)
        return null;    // or other default value
    ...
}

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I think this the reason of this behavior is that DataGrid renders whole its  templates on page render and call tooltip without data and data source. If you set property via my first code example there is nothing to render and converter calls only after Data was binded.

**UPDATE**
To manipulate isolated column in similar case you can change style or template of this column instead of RowStyle like int the example below:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="customTasksDataGrid" ItemsSource="..." IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Klient" Binding="{Binding Name}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, this code works for me, but I got issue with the next step.
Changing background color of entire row works perfect, but how to change background of only one cell in my datagrid using these functions? Of course I changed `ToolTipService.ToolTip` to `Background`

Comment: @MarcinZdunek is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values) helps you? Just change DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle instead of row style.

Comment: but I need to change cell color having info of entire object stored in one row. For example cell color is based on 2 object's parameters

Comment: @MarcinZdunek sorry for the long time answer. I updated my post.