# Change background color of datagrid cell depending on object property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I create columns in an data grid via code-behind like this:

```
DataGridTextColumn dgtc1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
dgtc1.Header = "Feldname";
dgtc1.Binding = new Binding("FieldName");
dataGrid.Columns.Add(dgtc1);
DataGridTextColumn dgtc2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
dgtc2.Header = "Masterwert";
dgtc2.Binding = new Binding("MasterValue");
dataGrid.Columns.Add(dgtc2);
int counter = 0;
foreach (DBManager database in databases)
{
    if (!database.IsMaster)
    {
        DataGridTextColumn dgtc = new DataGridTextColumn();
        dgtc.Header = database.DisplayName;
        dgtc.Binding = new Binding("LocationValues[" + counter + "]");
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(dgtc);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

I want the cells to change their background color to a specific value depending on the items property "DeltaValues".

```
if(DeltaValues[i] == true)
   //Change the background color to x
else
   //Do nothing
```

Is there a Binding I could set for the columns from code-behind to achieve this behaviour?

Any ideas?

Comment: XAML can just be translated, so there are many solutions to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values/5551986#5551986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not tested codes. I'm not sure DataGridCell.ContentProperty is correct property.:

```
if (!database.IsMaster)
{
    DataGridTextColumn dgtc = new DataGridTextColumn();
    dgtc.Header = database.DisplayName;
    dgtc.Binding = new Binding("LocationValues[" + counter + "]");

    Setter setter = new Setter();
    setter.Property = Control.BackgroundProperty;            
    setter.Value = Brushes.Red;

    Trigger trigger = new Trigger();
    trigger.Property = DataGridCell.ContentProperty;
    trigger.Value = true;
    trigger.Setters.Add(setter);

    dgtc.CellStyle.Triggers.Add(trigger);

    dataGrid.Columns.Add(dgtc);
    counter++;
}
```

or version with converter.

```
{
        if (!database.IsMaster)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn dgtc = new DataGridTextColumn();
            dgtc.Header = database.DisplayName;
            dgtc.Binding = new Binding("LocationValues[" + counter + "]");

            Converter converter = new Converter();

            Binding binding = new Binding(DeltaValues[i]);
            binding.Converter = converter;

            dgtc.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, binding));

            dataGrid.Columns.Add(dgtc);
            counter++;
        }


        return this;
    }
```

and very simple converter class:

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if ((bool)value) return Brushes.Red;

    return null;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    new throw Exception();
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay. And how do I bind like this in the background?

Comment: You binding background in CellTemplate. As soon as you write code.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: I saw already a lot of these implementations. The problem is, that I cannot define the columns in XAML. I have to do this from code-behind. And I dont know how to implement it from there.

Comment: That looks good so far. But in your example the change depends on the content of the cell which background has to be changed, right? I need it to depend on the value of a property of the bound item. `DeltaValues[i]` should be the dependant.

Comment: Your last code worked like a charm. Thank you very much! :)