# C# WPF Datagrid coloring a cell with code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in my Project with some Columns which are filles with PropertyDataBinding.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataOutOfDb" Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="500" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=ZeichnungCollection}" Margin="47,10,1299,0" SelectionChanged="dataOutOfDb_SelectionChanged" CanUserAddRows="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MouseDoubleClick="dataOutOfDb_MouseDoubleClick" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Zeichnungsnummer" Binding="{Binding AddColumnZeichnungsnummer, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Index" Binding="{Binding AddColumnIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="V-ID" Binding="{Binding AddColumnVolanteIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Änderung Intern" Binding="{Binding AddColumnAenderungIntern, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Änderung Extern" Binding="{Binding AddColumnAenderungExtern, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dateiendung" Binding="{Binding AddColumnExtension, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding AddColumnStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now I want that the last Column "Status" has a Color depending on the status itself. Like that only the Cell in the Row is green or red.

The class of the Properties is ISerializable and the Properties are filled like that:

```
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    this.GetObjectData(info, context);
    info.AddValue("AddColumnZeichnungsnummer", Zeichnungsnummer, typeof(string));
    info.AddValue("AddColumnIndex", Index, typeof(string));
    info.AddValue("AddColumnVolanteIndex", Volante_Index, typeof(int));
    info.AddValue("AddColumnAenderungIntern", Aenderung_Int, typeof(string));
    info.AddValue("AddColumnAenderungExtern", Aenderung_Ext, typeof(string));
    info.AddValue("AddColumnExtension", Extension, typeof(string));
    info.AddValue("AddColumnStatus", Status, typeof(string));
}
```

Has someone an idea to how to set the Status Cell with a Color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried that, with the direct Background-Binding out; it doesn´t cause any error, but the cell doesn´t change the color

Defining a CellStyle with a Background Setter will change the background of the cell:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding AddColumnStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

If you want to set the Background property of the cell based on the value of your AddColumnStatus property, you need to specify a DataTrigger for each possible value that this property may have. The following sample markup will set the Background property to Green when the AddColumnStatus property returns "YourStatusA" and to Red when it returns "YourStatusB":

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding AddColumnStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AddColumnStatus}" Value="YourStatusA">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AddColumnStatus}" Value="YourStatusB">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Also note that if you intend to change the value of the AddColumnStatus property dynamically at runtime and want the colour in the cell to be updated, the class wherw the AddColumnStatus property is defined should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise change notifications: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don´t know if it´s the best way to do it, but it seems to be the simpliest way. I just need to take a note to correct the xaml code when I edit a Status.

Comment: Using a CellStyle is certainly the best way and recommended way to change the colour of a cell in a DataGrid.

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty common in the wpf Datagrid world, I recommand you to refer to this topic [Change DataGrid cell colour based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values), where @H.B. gives a pertinent answer on how to do it in a correct way.

Comment: Thank you for your very good link. I tried that, with the direct Background-Binding out; it doesn´t cause any error, but the cell doesn´t change the color.

Comment: "You will have to fire property change notifications in the setters of properties on which the colour is dependent." Did you notice this part ? You'll have to add OnPropertyChanged("NameBrush"); in your setter of Status

Comment: Yes I read that in I tried to add the OnPropertyChanged(...) but i cant call this method in my Setter. Have you an idea what I did wrong?