# InvalidOperationException in WPF form when trying to change cell color in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I cannot say that I am new to WPF, because it would be too much. I just was given with WPF app to maintain...

I need to change particular cell color in `DataGrid` based on a value. I thought it would be easy, found that SO post: [Change DataGrid cell colour based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values)
.

Pasted where it belongs, which gave me the following:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DgDevices" ItemsSource="{Binding}" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2" Cursor="Cross">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu >
            <MenuItem Header="Załóż Deblokadę" Click="InsertDBL"  />
            <MenuItem Header="Usuń Deblokadę" Click="RemoveDBL"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

Now, when invoking `Show` method on this form, it gives me `InvalidOperationException`. I searched for explanation why this happens, but haven't found clear explanation.

Also, I know that `Binding Name` is placeholder for my binding (in `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">`), so I tired putting just `Binding` there (inspired by `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` in `DataGrid` node), but didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried removing xaml until it works to cancel out and narrow down what the problem is... i don't know about you, but when i get weird errors, i find it an invaluable debugging tool

Comment: As I explained, after pasting whole `<DataGridTextColumn>` crashes the app (taken directly from mentioned post). Should I try and delete smaller parts?

Comment: Thats what id do, remove small parts until it dosnt throw any more, add it back until you work out what line it is, then you can search for a more direct answer

Comment: Could you post exception details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are now adding `DataGridTextColumn` right into `DataGrid` itself, not to its columns list. Adding items directly and using `ItemsSource` are mutually exclusive, so `InvalidOperationException` is thrown (and you didn't intend to add column as item anyway). Instead, do it like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DgDevices"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          BorderThickness="2,0,2,2"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          Cursor="Cross">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu >
            <MenuItem Header="Załóż Deblokadę" Click="InsertDBL"  />
            <MenuItem Header="Usuń Deblokadę" Click="RemoveDBL"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <DataGrid.Columns> <!-- add to columns -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text"
                                 Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="Black" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Also, because you need to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False`, because otherwise `DataGrid` will automatically generate columns from your data source, in addition to columns you define manually, and you rarely need that.

Comment: I set in my code `DataContext` of `DataGrid`, which adds columns to already defined. Can I define all needed columns and fill them with `DataTable`? Or it will allways add `DataTable` column to existing ones? (Anyway, great answer, cleared a lot to me, +1 :) )

Comment: @MichałTurczyn not sure I understood correctly, but you I think you need to have a look at AutoGenerateColumns property of DataGrid. If set to true (default) - it will autogenerate columns based on your source. If you define your own column - you need to set that to false and define all columns yourself. Otherwise - it will add autogenerated columns _on top_ of columns you defined.

Comment: So, to apply your answer, I need to set it to false, define all column in XAML, then populate it?

Comment: Yes, either all columns are autogenerated, or all columns are defined manually in xaml. Since you need to define at least one column manually - you need to define them all.

Comment: Great, very helpful and clear! Let me check fully your answer, then I'll accept it :)