# Changing cell color of a datagrid based on a datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a datatable and I want to change the color of the cells in my datagrid according to the values of the datatable.

for example in some cells, the fields are written: invalid, busy. When it is invalid I want to leave your background with red color, and how much is busy I want to leave with green color

**DataTable**

```
     0     1     3     4
0 invalid

1              invalid

2

3 invalid

4                     invalid
```

so in my datagrid coordinates (0,0), (3,0), (3,1) and (4,4) I want to paint your red background

how is this possible?
I tried to do it the following way

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gvPreV" RowHeaderWidth = "70" CanUserAddRows="True" SelectionUnit="Cell"  Margin="10,117,10,10" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding}"  FontSize="16" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  AllowDrop="True" 
                    Background="White" ColumnHeaderHeight="30" MinColumnWidth="150" 
                    LoadingRow="gvDados_LoadingRow" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                    AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFF9F9F9" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF252424"
                    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF2B2828" MouseDoubleClick="gvPreV_MouseDoubleClick" BorderBrush="#FFB6B6B6" HeadersVisibility="All"
                     SelectionChanged="gvPreV_SelectionChanged" RowHeight="40" MinRowHeight="40" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"        
                 >

        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>         
                <Style.Triggers>                        
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="invalid">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>                         
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>

    </DataGrid>
```

I have a Variable Name and it is set to invalid, so it would already leave all invalids of the expected color but that does not work, everything turns green

```
  string Name = "invalid";
  public ViewConfigAgendaDin()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      Inicializa();
      gvPreV.ItemsSource = null;
      gvPreV.ItemsSource = dtPreVisualizacao.DefaultView;
      gvPreV.UpdateLayout();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<Style TargetType="{x:DataGridCell}"` instead.

Comment: This does not work, the datagridcell type is not found

Comment: Have you checked this post? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values

Comment: yes, it also did not work even though I was trying to do <Style  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

Comment: What happens when you remove `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>`

Comment: the datagrid cells return the default color, apparently this is working with the DataTrigger

Comment: Can you add further code to show how your `Name` string is added to your `DataGrid` please? Are you using a `TextBlock`?

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my question by adding more source code

Comment: What is dtPreVisualizacao and how does the string Name get into the DataTable? It looks to me as though you have just set up an extra string for 'Name' but that it isn't the same string being inserted into the DataTable, therefor binding to it won't work.

Comment: my dtprevisualization is the datatable with the data, it has the data that is invalid and valid, for example dtpreviewing.rows [0] [5] = "invalid". like I can do then for my datagrid to change the color according to the datatable