# WPF datagrid and rows coloring

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to perform something that would be simple in WinForms, but turned to be close to impossible with WPF. I need to color rows (very long, a lot of values) using two shades (one for odd rows, one for even rows - aka AlternatingRowBackground). It seems that - if I set any brush to AlternatingRowBackground, whatever I'm trying to set over that (i.e. bound some value in my data table to make some rows highlighted with red background) - manipulating RowStyle or trying to force row background inside LoadedRow event function - all of it is ignored. If I will remove AlternatingRowBackground brush, RowStyle starts working, but I have no alternating rows shades.

So I tried to use MultiDataTrigger to (multi)bind this value that suppose to highlight and something that would show me row index - to manually create regular / alternating colors. I need that because DataGrid is filtered. I cannot use some fake value in data table to determine current row index. In other words - DataGrid row index is not same as data table row index. I tried to bind DataGridRow itself. But row, during conversion, has no index within datagrid (always -1).

Is there any way to have both AlternatingRowColor set and some rows highlighted with different background same time?

Comment: May second answer in [>THIS<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values) question will be helpful. You can try with RowStyle instead of CellStyle.

Comment: It would be helpfully to see your XAML. Also please take a minute and read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but - Wojtman - I think You meant using CellStyle instead RowStyle. Rekshino : I'm not doing it in XAML. for many reasons, I need to do that in code (not just one datagrid, an array of datagrids, etc.). To me - it's kind of a unclear where to add CellStyle. I did that in an event function that is serving AutoGenerating columns. However - in here - I still have no access to current RowIndex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a precedence. Values set in attributes have higher precedence as set in styles. So if you set `AlternatingRowBackground` in a `Style` and not as element's attribute all will work as intended:

```
<DataGrid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="Aquamarine"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Style>
```

Comment: Excellent tip. Thank You. This is one of those things in WPF I couldn't find anywhere. Priorities of things.