# How to change background color of a cell in WPF datagrid based on its value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I would like to Change the Background of a cells in a wpf datagrid according to ist value. My datagrid is as follows:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridView_Comparison" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"    AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AlternationCount="2"  Height="537" Margin="15,48,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1016" Background="#FF2C2727" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{DynamicResource DGHeaderStyle}" selectionUnit="FullRow">
```

I am creating this datagrid dynamically in c# as the no of columns always vary depending on the Input. The Code part which does it is :

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
        foreach (string num in numbersList)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(num, typeof(string)); //Adding each numbers as a column in the table
        }
        foreach (string tc in uniqueCases)
        {
            DataRow newRow = table.NewRow(); 

            newRow["Column1"] = tc+"_Case"; //Adding the case name of the row
            foreach (string num in numbersList)
            {
                //For each number column add value corresponding to the condition..
                newRow[num] = "0"; //Default value as 0
                if (list_beforeThreshold.ContainsKey(num + tc) == true)
                {
                    newRow[num] = "1";
                }
                if (list_afterThreshold.ContainsKey(num + tc) == true)
                {
                    newRow[num] = "2";
                }
            table.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
```

dataGridView_Comparison.DataContext = table.DefaultView; //Adding to the datagrid in wpf

I am fairly new in c# and wpf. Could someone please guide me on how to give differenet Colors to cell depending on their values(0,1,2). 
PS: I am trying datatrigger now. But not getting any Progress.

EDIT 1: The no of columns and the names of columns cannot be hardcoded in the xaml because they are dynamically populated in c#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5549617/1136211 and similar other questions.

Comment: @Clemens I have tried most of those Solutions. They didnt solve my issue as my datagrid columns are not static. Since i am a newbie in wpf i am not sure whether i am following the right way of Building the datatable for my datagrid

Answer (score 1):

This `DataTrigger` is applied to all cells in the `DataGrid`. When the criteria is met the trigger will change the colour, when the criteria is unmet it will change back.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Property}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **IValueConverter** to change the background color.

**Define Converter class in xaml:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NameToBrushConverter x:Key="NameToBrushConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="testDG" ItemsSource="{Binding tempData}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource NameToBrushConverter}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**Converter Class:**

```
public class NameToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string input = value as string;
    switch (input)
    {
        case "Smith":
            return Brushes.LightGreen;
        case "Willam":
            return Brushes.LightPink;
        default:
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
 }
 public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
 {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
 } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you can see in my code the column names are dynamically populated in the c# code. So i cannot give like {Binding Name}. I need to access the value of each cell and if its 0 - red , 1 - yellow , 2 - red something like this. The no of columns and the names of columns cannot be hardcoded in the xaml as i said before, is dynamically populated.

Comment: how dynamically are they populated, what are you changing the color based upon. Could you put something in the `Tag` and then bind the `DataTrigger` to that?

Comment: @user8478480 I am creating the columns in c# code like below: foreach (string num in numbersList)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(num, typeof(string)); //Adding each numbers as a column in the table
        }  
And for each column, based on some condition im populating value as either 0,or 1 or 2. So based on this values(0 or 1 or 2) i need to color that cell. Example cell having 0 needs to be in grey color , with value 1 needs to be in yellow and 2 in green.

Comment: You would be much better off binding your `DataGrid` to collection and defining the columns template in the `XAML` manually, this way you can have the triggers you need.

Comment: Do you have any pointers on how to populate the columns dynamically in xaml and bind data from c#