# Wpf Datagrid dynamic columns how to color cell in row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

This datagrid is generated dynamically - list of columns is changing - there is no XAML definition of columns - but list of rows is always 6 with different colors of each row

I have this code to color entire row in wpf datadrid:

```
private void dgrid2_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView x = (DataRowView)e.Row.Item;

    if (x[0].ToString() == "auto1")
    {
        Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF88B149");
        e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    if (x[0].ToString() == "auto2")
    {
        Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#ffe17177");
        e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);

    }
}
```

but how to get the color in cells where there is some value and in those where there is null that the background is white

Comment: See [Change DataGrid cell colour based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change DataGrid cell colour based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549617/change-datagrid-cell-colour-based-on-values)

Comment: I added some code and some explanation