# Changing datagrid cell color

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

This is frequent question, but still don't know how to make it work. I'm performing a logger and want to set red color on cell. XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:LogLevelToColorConverter  x:Key="colorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgLog"   AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Date and time" Binding="{Binding DateTime}"  Width="120"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Message1" Binding="{Binding Message}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                            Value="{Binding Color}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Message2" Binding="{Binding Message}" Foreground="{Binding Level,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"/>
           
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
namespace DGTest {
public class LogLevelToColorConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (value is string level) {
            var brush = Brushes.White;
            if (level == "WARN") {
                brush = Brushes.Yellow;
            }
            else if (level == "ERROR") {
                brush = Brushes.Red;
            }
            return brush;

        }
        return Brushes.White;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class LogMessage {
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Brush Color { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    readonly ObservableCollection<LogMessage> logMessages = new ObservableCollection<LogMessage>();
    
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgLog.ItemsSource = logMessages;
        logMessages.Add(new LogMessage { DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(), Level = "ERROR", Message = "Test message", Color = Brushes.Red });
    }
}
```

Tried to pass Brush in "Color" field directly - not working (Message1 column). Tried with Converter (Message2 column), still no result. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I think you have possibly already used some of the code from this previous answer, but it looks like you glossed over the first code snippet using `Trigger Property` in your XAML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5551986/13108684 which might make it easier for you, as you could set up the different conditions for the `level` and set different foreground colours on the cell

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this approach works fine, just tested it. But I need to paint cell with  message too (not only cell with level).

Comment: Aren't you already doing that for the cell with the header: `Message1`? Using `{Binding Message}`. When I run it locally, it works correctly and changes the `Text Colour` to `Red`, it won't change the cell Background as you are setting the `Foreground` colour, please can you try and clarify what you mean

Comment: I want to change Text color (foreground). But no effect.

Comment: Try changing the `<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>` to: `<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>` then changing the `<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">` to: `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">` and give that a go as that is what I've done and this is my result: https://i.gyazo.com/07a0065ce18b630629f796eb8cb12030.png

Answer (score 2):

`MainWindow` View:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgLog" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Date and time" Binding="{Binding DateTime}"  Width="120"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Message" Binding="{Binding Message}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Color}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

`LogMessage` Class:

```
public class LogMessage
{
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Brush Color { get; set; }
}
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    readonly ObservableCollection<LogMessage> logMessages = new ObservableCollection<LogMessage>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgLog.ItemsSource = logMessages;
        logMessages.Add(new LogMessage 
        { 
            DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(), 
            Level = "ERROR", 
            Message = "Test message", 
            Color = Brushes.Red
        });
    }
}
```

Result screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of App]

Comment: As you can see, the only thing I have changed is `DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle` and the `TargetType` and it is working as you require.

Comment: Still no result: very strange https://ibb.co/f9pvPmw

Comment: Can you re-build your project to make sure it's up to date? I don't know why you aren't getting the same result, if a rebuild doesn't work, possibly closing and re-opening Visual Studio might help, as like I said, the code I've sent is working correctly and minimal change compared to your original code

Comment: Rebooted the system, rebuilt/cleaned th project. Still no result, thats depressing... Stranger things... Could you send an archive with sources on mail?

Comment: Also rebuilt on Win8.1 OS. I'm using Win10 normally. WTF